# KL Divergence Between Ground Truth and Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, model-evaluation, boosting, kullback-leibler

I've got four (non-linear, tree-based) models in production and using the average of them as the served prediction. We get ground truth data immediately.

During training the optimized candidate models had very similar performance, so I decided to deploy all of them and take the average and served that as the prediction. With the intention of figuring which one would really be best at a later point.

That later point has come.

Out of these four models two seem fit the ground truth distribution quite well, at least by examining the KDE plot of the predicted values against the ground truth distribution

I was initially thinking of doing a pairwise 2-sample KS Test (each model against ground truth) to see if the predicted values from the models come from the same distribution as the ground truth.

But I talked myself out of it. Mostly because I have 50,000+ predictions and I figured that a sample size that large will result in a small p-value anyway.

I then turned my attention to KL divergence. Something I have never used before.

Would comparing the KL-Divergence between each model's prediction and the ground truth be a good way to assess model fit?

If so, how would I go about doing this? `scipy.stats.kl_div` outputs an array which contains (I assume) the divergence between the prediction and ground truth.

Would I just take the sum of the array and call that the Divergence between the model and ground truth?

Hopefully I don't sound crazy or too much like I don't know what I'm doing or talking about. Because I kinda don't, but not too much.

Thank you

Comment: > Would comparing the KL-Divergence between each model's prediction and the ground truth be a good way to assess model fit?


On an abstract level, sure, but as a matter of practice, you want your assessment to accurately represent the use case. You can't always train your model using your ideal performance metric as a loss function, but you can still use it for assessing accuracy. If you're using KL-Divergence you're either doing binary classification or multi-class classification. There are useful performance measures for binary classification that lack obvious multiclass counterparts.

Comment: @AlexEftimiades - in my case the model output and ground truth are both continuous. What would work better in this case?

Comment: So you're doing regression? Mean squared or absolute error are common and fairly interpretable measures in that case. What's your loss function? With regression you can often make the loss function the same as the performance metric (if not you should probably have a decent reason). BTW if your ground truth is still being interpreted as probabilities you can still technically use KL divergence. Context is important!

Comment: Hi @AlexEftimiades - thanks for the response. I am doing a regression. My loss function is mean absolute error, and this is also my performance metric. The ground truth in this case would be a real value number, not a probability.